# Indexing Double Float Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I add values to this kind of array?

```
let data = [(x: Float, y: Float)]()
```

How can i change indexes and add new float values while storing the ones I already added.

Example:

```
[(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), (x: 1.0, y: 2.0), (x: 2.0, y: 3.0)]
```

Comment: Can you explain your question more elaborately? What do you mean by change indexes and add new float values while storing the ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own data structure.

```
class myData: CustomStringConvertible {
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
    init(x: Float, y: Float) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }

    var description: String {
        return "[x = \(x), y = \(y)]"
    }
}

var dataArray = [myData]()
let mockData = [myData(x: 1, y: 2), myData(x: 3, y: 4)]

dataArray.append(contentsOf: mockData)
print(dataArray)
// -->[[x = 1.0, y = 2.0], [x = 3.0, y = 4.0]]

// you can change the value at any index of your data
dataArray[0].x = 4
print(dataArray)
// --> [[x = 4.0, y = 2.0], [x = 3.0, y = 4.0]]

//Also, you can change all values this way
dataArray.map { $0.y = 5 }
print(dataArray)
// -->[[x = 4.0, y = 5.0], [x = 3.0, y = 5.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` method to add more tuple values in data.

```
data.append((1.0, 20.0))
data.append((1.0, 3.0))
```

and if you want to update the value

```
data[0] = (2.0, 4.0)
```

And if you want to change specific index x and y values:

```
data[0].x = 4.0 //or     data[0].0 = 4.0
data[0].y = 6.0 // or     data[0].1 = 7.0
```

Comment: What if i want to change the value of the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

answer above is only half correct, you need to change keyword let hence it is for constant to var

```
var data = [(x: Float, y: Float)]()
data.append(contentsOf: [(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), (x: 1.0, y: 2.0), (x: 2.0, y: 3.0)])
```

Comment: im confused on data[0].x  and data[0].y how does this store? and you guys have different indexes